Type-safe function to merge path segments based on an array of keys
The following Paths type represents a number of url paths broken up by path segment.
type PathSegment = {
    path: string;
    children: Paths;
}

type Paths = Record<string, PathSegment | string>;

The following is an example object matching this type:
const paths: Paths = {
    home: "/",
    profile: "/profile",
    settings: {
        path: "/settings",
        children: {
            general: "/general",
            account: "/account",
        }
    }
}

Is it possible to create a function that merges path segments together in a type-safe way by providing the keys of the paths that should be merged? For example, given the paths object above, I could do something like:
const accountSettingsPath = mergePathSegments(paths, ["settings", "account"]);
console.log(accountSettingsPath); // outputs "/settings/account"

The keys passed in via the array should be known at compile-time so that a typo can't be made. And the array can't be bigger than the number of keys that are available. Is something like this possible?

• Are you asking us to provide the typings for mergePathSegments? Or the implementation (I hope not both, because they are effectively unrelated in terms of how you need to do this with TS)? It seems to me the implementation is easy for you to do and the typings is hard, so here's a playground link showing the typings. (Note that you can't use const paths: Paths =  or you've thrown away the info you care about. satisfies is the approach you need.) Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer; if not, please [edit] so it clarifies what I'm missing.

You can build types for both input and output path using recursion:
Playground
type PathSegment = {
    path: string;
    children: Paths;
}

type Paths = Record<string, PathSegment | string>;

const paths = {
    home: "/",
    profile: "/profile",
    settings: {
        path: "/settings",
        children: {
            general: "/general",
            account: "/account",
        }
    }
} as const satisfies Paths;

type Breadcrumbs<T extends Paths> = 
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? 
    [K] : 
    T[K] extends PathSegment ? 
      [K, ... Breadcrumbs<T[K]['children']>] : 
      never 
  }[keyof T];

type MakePath<T extends Paths, B extends Breadcrumbs<T>> = 
  {[K in B[0]]: T[K] extends string ? 
    T[K] : 
    T[K] extends PathSegment ?  
      `${T[K]['path']}${B extends [string, ...infer C] ? C extends Breadcrumbs<T[K]['children']> ? MakePath<T[K]['children'], C> : '' : ''}` : 
      never 
  }[B[0]];

declare function mergePathSegments<T extends Paths, const B extends Breadcrumbs<T>>(paths: T, breadcrumbs: B): MakePath<T, B> extends `${infer A}` ? A : string

const accountSettingsPath = mergePathSegments(paths, ["settings", "account"]); // "/settings/account"
console.log(accountSettingsPath); // outputs "/settings/account"


Does the OP actually need as const and something more complex than string as an output? Is that clear from the question?

@jcalz just an option how i would implement it ‍♂️
